# show splash screen while Webview is loading in background

Tags: java, android, android-layout, webview

I'm using below code to populate my Main activity with Webview, but as it takes a certain time to load the page and it appears white blank. So I will like to show splash screen for my Webview before page load finishes. I'm not using any webview from Layout activity.

```
package com.faraksoch.sagar.facebook;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebview = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    mWebview = new WebView(this);

    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

    final Activity activity = this;

    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com//");
    setContentView(mWebview);

}
```

}

I know that this code should work but I when I combine them..it won't work

```
  WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        ...

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //hide loading image
            findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //show webview
            findViewById(R.id.webView1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


    });     
    wv.loadUrl("http://yoururlhere.com");
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try placing log in `onPageFinished` and see if it is getting called or not.

Comment: @Michal_196 can you please show me how.....!! everything I did learn so far is from examples and tutorials.so I really have not that much..what to do

Comment: what do you mean by combine? You don't want to load webview through xml layout file

Comment: @jiteshmohite yes jites..when I load the webview from xml layout then the screean appears blank and white...but only with my sites but it works fine with youtube or google...which is of no use to me. I want to load my own blog which appears blank when I use layout xml. so I searched on internet and found above solution which works for me...but now I have no idea how to show image before webview loads the page which I could do if I had use layout instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure webview is visibility is not GONE before it is loading.

Please refer below code.

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    private ImageView mSplashView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mSplashView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_view);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                mSplashView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Page Loaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://yoururlhere.com");
        mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mSplashView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @Caterpillar welcome. If you need any help you can mail me jiteshmohite619@gmail.com